# Effect of the Flux on the universe?

Tags: doctor-who

Has there been any explanation of what state the universe is in after the Flux was defeated?

It seemingly destroyed both the Dalek and Sontaran fleets, but the Daleks are back and just fine.

In the solar system alone, it ate most of the outer planets, which would play merry hell with the orbits of the remaining planets.

I can write off the people of Earth just assuming that it was all a publicity stunt or something (cause we're thick) but considering a pretty damned large amount of places were destroyed, we're in a post-Endgame level of devastation.

Did it all just snap back to normal somehow?  Anything in any official sources?

Comment: You expect continuity when in fact, none exists.

Comment: Keeping in mind that there is time travel involved, any defeat or extinction will be fleeting.  Any time traveler can go pick up samples throughout the species' existence, to be produced anywhen else.

Answer (score 1):

There are some hints in the very next episode, *Eve of the Daleks*, but they are not terribly satisfactory.

Firstly, the Doctor was working to reset the effects of The Flux on the TARDIS:

> DOCTOR: When I set this going, the Tardis will go into self-reset, which should - if I've got this right, which I'm sure I have - clear out all the Flux debris, minimise the number of doors, and be back to fully functioning. But it'll be out of service for a little bit.

Later in the same episode, Dan makes this throwaway comment:

> But you saved **the entire universe** last week. I think I owe you one.

So, although there is no further detail given, apparently, we have to conclude that the Doctor *did* somehow either save the "entire universe", or secure what was left of it so that nobody needs to worry about how the Earth could survive and stay in orbit around its own sun with most of the universe missing.

Comment: Plus the entire thing is going to be memory-holed by the new makers.